# Why didn't Ego create another copy?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In the movie *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*, Kurt Russell's character is a fabrication of energy (the Light). So in the end when he is fighting Star-Lord (Peter Quill), when there is a bomb ticking, why didn't Ego create another fragment that would save him?

I even thought about a possible explanation: because Peter was controlling the Light, Ego couldn't. But Kurt's character was still healing, so both had access to the Light.

So what could be the reason?

---

#### Edit1:

Ego started as a planet and using his knowledge, he created layers which led to a planet like entity.

For reference:

[image]

You can read more here [Ego - Wiki](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Ego)

Comment: He was probably unaware of Baby Groot and the bomb plan seeing as Peter was intentionally distracting him. All his focus was on fighting Peter.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder in that case, why was he so desperate at the end. He was aware about the bomb and groot. That is the reason he closed the tunnel groot was in. He is also shown to have conversations with Peter that if he destroys the light, he will loose the connection and will become a mere mortal.

Comment: I don't really see how your second point is relevant. As to the first it's been a while since I watched the film so this may not be accurate but it could be that he only became aware later on at which point it was too late to save himself. Or he didn't know how to etc etc

Answer (score 5):

> Ego's brain is the structure that determined whether Ego was alive or dead. Creating another body would not save the brain, which was inside the core of the planet.

Note that Ego emerged as pure consciousness in the distant past, and that Ego's consciousness created the brain inside Ego's planet as a tool to assist in his work.

A better question might be why Ego did not create more than one brain or more than one planet, each with multiple brains.  Perhaps in a future reboot, he will.  But in this incarnation Ego chose to extend by planting seeds across the galaxy.that leverage the energy flowing through a single brain core on his single home planet.  This left Ego vulnerable to the bomb that baby Groot is placing in the photo in the following link:

[image: Groot with Kaboo-ey]

Comment: Is that quote genuinely sourced from somewhere or just on a code block cuz it looks good?

Comment: @Edlothiad I saw the movie six times and also asked several questions about the movie on this site about the movie in the course of researching the topic. I am confident that the source material is accurately reflected in this answer.

Comment: Not questioning the accuracy at all, was just wondering if the quote block was your own words or not.

Comment: No. Ego started as a brain and this brain created layers eventually resulting in a planet. So, the second body could crawl down like baby groot and eradicate the bomb.

Comment: Better documenta supports what is written in this answer. However, I am on my phone and not able to address this today.

Comment: I agree that what you say is true, but it doesn't seem to address the question being asked: why didn't Ego create another body to stop Groot from placing the bomb, or to remove the bomb after it was placed?

Comment: Or just use those tentacle things to dispose of the bomb. When it comes to fighting Peter it seems there is no limit to the matter manipulation he is capable of. He also knows about the bomb before it goes off and he pleads with Peter to stop it, so it's not like he was caught unawares.